# Custom unwind segue animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, transition, segue

I have the following set up:

[image: Setup idea]

The red controller has a method

```
- (IBAction)unwindToRed:(UISegue *)segue
```

and a

```
- (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

which returns a custom segue for this event.

In my custom segue I have the following in the perform code:

```
- (void)perform
{
    // Just helpers to get the controllers from the segue
    UIViewController *destination = self.destinationViewController;
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;

    // Setting transitioning delegate for custom transitions
    destination.transitioningDelegate = self;
    source.transitioningDelegate = self;

    destination.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    source.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    // When I am transitioning to a new one
    if(!self.reversed)
    {
        [source presentViewController:destination animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    // Or reversing from a current one
    else
    {
        [source dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

As you can see I have setup a transition delegate which which in turn calls

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
```

on an animation controller where I apply my custom animation. But now when I tap Unwind to Red on the yellow view, it only "unwinds" to its parent. (e.g the blue one).

When I leave the custom segue out of the equation it works just fine. It goes al the way to the top.

Now I think this has to do with the

```
[source dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

line, since that usually just goes "one up" my question is I think, what should I call there so it goes all the way up to red when needed? Yellow is a modal overlay. So "pop too root" would not work.

Comment: How does your ```transitionContext``` look like about the source, destination, frames and container? I think you shouldn't use ```[source dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];```, you should just call ```[transitionContext completeTransition:YES];```

Answer (score 1):

### Specifing a Custom Segue

The solution was to use a custom segue for the unwind. **Unfortunately you cannot specify a custom segue for an unwind in interface builder like you can on a normal segue. You have to specify it with code.**

There is a function on `UIViewController` that you can override called `segueForUnwindingToViewController` which specifies which segue to use for the unwind. The tricky part is knowing which view controller to override this function on. The answer is to do it on the parent of the view controllers you are transitioning to/from. In my case it is the `UINavigationController`. The navigation controller is the container view controller for the first and third view controller. If I had embedded child view controllers in my views, then the answer would not be the navigation controller but the parent view controller.

Create a custom navigation controller by inheriting from `UINavigationController`. Then make sure to set the custom class of your navigation controller in interface builder. Now you can override the `segueForUnwindingToViewController` function. Here is a minimal implementation.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController,
                                                    fromViewController: UIViewController,
                                                    identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
        return UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController)
    }
}
```

### Adding Animation to Custom Segue

```
override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController,
                                                    fromViewController: UIViewController,
                                                    identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
        return UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController) {
            let fromView = fromViewController.view
            let toView = toViewController.view
            if let containerView = fromView.superview {
                let initialFrame = fromView.frame
                var offscreenRect = initialFrame
                offscreenRect.origin.x -= CGRectGetWidth(initialFrame)
                toView.frame = offscreenRect
                containerView.addSubview(toView)
                // Being explicit with the types NSTimeInterval and CGFloat are important
                // otherwise the swift compiler will complain
                let duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0
                let delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0
                let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut
                let damping: CGFloat = 0.5
                let velocity: CGFloat = 4.0
                UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: damping,
                        initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: options, animations: {
                    toView.frame = initialFrame
                }, completion: { finished in
                    toView.removeFromSuperview()
                    if let navController = toViewController.navigationController {
                        navController.popToViewController(toViewController, animated: false)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Details are [from this post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/03/ios-unwind-segue-custom-animation/)

Comment: `segueForUnwindingToViewController(to:from:identifier:)` was deprecated in iOS10.

Comment: and you can now specify custom class for unwind

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Navigation controller's popToViewController:

```
 [source.navigationController popToViewController:destination animated:YES];
```

or, use `animated:NO` and put the whole thing in an animation block: e.g.:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions animation  = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent;

UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dest = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;


[UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.4
                   options: animation
                animations:^{
                    [source.navigationController popToViewController:dest animated:NO];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                }];
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your `UIStoryboardSegue` implementation. Was your use of `modalTransitionStyle` a typo in your post or in your actual code? Corrected:

   ```
   destination.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
   ```
2. I have also had success without writing a custom `UIStoryboardSegue`.  Try linking an "unwind to Red" button's action method to an empty `-unwindToRed:` method without overriding `-segueForUnwindingToViewController:`  (e.g. CTRL+drag from the button in the blue VC to the blue VC's "Exit" glyph in IB and select `-unwindToRed:` from the list.)
3. If #2 does not dismiss the blue VC, you could try invoking the following manually in `-unwindToRed:` IBAction method:

   ```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   ```